# Augment size of a tf.variable

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am training an `autoencoder` by giving 2 placeholders that store the following:

```
x1 = [x1]

X = [x1,x2,x3...xn]
```

It holds that:

```
y1 = W*x1 + b_encoding1
```

Therefore, I have a variable named `b_encoder1` (the b)
(When I print it I get: `<tf.Variable 'b_encoder1:0' shape=(10,) dtype=float32_ref>`)

But it also holds that:

```
Y = W*X + b_encoding1
```

The size of the second `b_encoding1` has to be `(10,n)` intead of `(10,)`. How can I augment it and pass it in `tensorflow`?

```
Y = tf.compat.v1.nn.xw_plus_b(X, W1, b_encoder1, name='Y')
```

The whole code looks like this:

```
x1 = tf.compat.v1.placeholder( tf.float32, [None,input_shape], name = 'x1')
X = tf.compat.v1.placeholder( tf.float32, [None,input_shape,sp], name = 'X')

W1 = tf.Variable(tf.initializers.GlorotUniform()(shape=[input_shape,code_length]),name='W1')
b_encoder1 = tf.compat.v1.get_variable(name='b_encoder1',shape=[code_length],initializer=tf.compat.v1.initializers.zeros(), use_resource=False)
K = tf.Variable(tf.initializers.GlorotUniform()(shape=[code_length,code_length]),name='K')
b_decoder1 = tf.compat.v1.get_variable(name='b_decoder1',shape=[input_shape],initializer=tf.compat.v1.initializers.zeros(), use_resource=False)

y1 = tf.compat.v1.nn.xw_plus_b(x1, W1, b_encoder1, name='y1')
Y = tf.compat.v1.nn.xw_plus_b(X, W1, b_encoder1, name='Y')
```

I also declare the loss function and so on and then train with:

```
with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:

    sess.run(tf.compat.v1.global_variables_initializer())

    for epoch_i in range(epochs):

        for batch_i in range(number_of_batches):

            batch_data = getBatch(shuffled_data, batch_i, batch_size)
            sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={x1: batch_data[:,:,0], X: batch_data})

        train_loss = sess.run(loss, feed_dict={x1: aug_data[:,:,0], X: aug_data})
        print(epoch_i, train_loss)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
b_encoding1 = tf.expand_dims(b_encoding1, axis = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can consider `X` as a batch of `x`. `X` can take in an arbitrary number of samples:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

X = tf.placeholder(shape=(None, 100), dtype=tf.float32)
W = tf.get_variable('kernel', [100,10])
b = tf.get_variable('bias',[10])
Y = tf.nn.xw_plus_b(X, W,b, name='Y')

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())  # tf version < 1.13
    out = sess.run(Y, {X: np.random.rand(128, 100)})  # here n=128
```

Note that dimension of bias `b` is still 10-D regardless value of n.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Should I then have one placeholder only (X) or do I keep x as well?

Comment: please check the updated question, as I was doing what you said already

Comment: @user11400799 You don't need x any more, as x is a special case of X with sp=1.